# How to don't include the google font css in one specific button only?

Tags: html, css

I am using Google Font like this:

```
<!--google web font-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic,700|Lato:700,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And I have a button like this:

```
<a href="/accounts/register"><button class="btn btn-success">Create an Account</button></a>
```

I don't want to include this `google font` in this specific button only. How can I do that?

Comment: Set that google font to all buttons, and then set some ID to this specific button with other google font or any other font (to override google font applied to all other buttons).

Comment: Use a link or a button, but not both. Either one by itself is a good way to add something the user can click on to cause an action to happen. Using both together is redundant and may confuse some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the parent ID that this button is nested in, and take control of the button's font type like this..

```
#Parent .btn-success {
font-family:arial; /*or whatever default font you want to give it*/
}
```

Now if you have more than one button on the page (if you do you should of showed that in your original question), 
then you can use jquery to add the css I just wrote above, to that specific button like this

```
$('#parent .btn-success').eq(0).css('font-family':'arial')
```

and  replace the 0 with  1 or 2 or 3, etc,...depending on where your button is located.

Comment: How could be a jquery solution better than a css one? I don't understand how did you decided that..

Comment: @MateiMihai it just depends on the situation. I never claimed this is the only way.  It's simply one of many ways to solve the problem, and it works for me since I am heavily into modifying class's, Id's and inline styles with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `button` inside `a` elements!

CSS:

```
a.btn {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* or other font family */
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/accounts/register" class="btn btn-success">Create an Account</a>
```

Comment: If he's using the button element already (and probably styling it to look like a button), why suggest removing `<button>` and using `<a>`?

Comment: because buttons don't have a `href` attribute and that means he must use javascript for redirecting the page and also means that search engines will not index that page..

Answer (score 0):

- You click that link : http://www.google.com/fonts/#HomePlace:home
- you follow the instructions

> To integrate the fonts into your CSS:
>
> The Google Web Fonts API will generate the necessary browser-specific
>   CSS to use the fonts. All you need to do is add the font name to your
>   CSS styles. For example: font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;

CSS

```
button.not-that-font {font-family: 'NOT YOUR GOOGLE API FONT', sans-serif;}
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-success not-that-font">Create an Account</button>
```

Comment: I have already integrated and it's working fine. But I don't want the google font to come out in this specific button only. That's it!

Comment: i edited my answer. how to NOT use a font .. You just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted does not actually take the Google font to any use, so you must have some CSS code that does that. You need to modify it so that the font is only used for those element to which you wish to apply it. The details depend on the code you have.

Generally, styling works best the positive way: set properties on specific elements only, instead of setting them e.g. to all elements and then wonder how to make some elements exceptions. But at the extreme, you could add an attribute like `id=foo` to the element to be excepted and append `:not(#foo)` to the selector(s) in the rule. But this is suboptimal because the `:not` selector is not universally supported.

Answer (score -1):

Add Inline style to the Button, Inline styles overrides all other CSS Styles.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" 
style="font-size:11px;">Create an Account</button>
```

Comment: Your markup is wrong (`<a>` shouldn't wrap `<button>`), and your advocating inline styles.

Comment: you are right Dawson, i just copy-pasted the code as it is.
i edited the code.